# It is not able to get even 'birthday' by using the FacebookProvider. Laravel 5.0

Tags: php, facebook, laravel-5

Log in to facebook in Laravel 5.0, we would want to get information.
Basic information you could get, can not be acquired only birthday.

AuthController.php

```
$socialite = Socialize::with('facebook')->scopes(['gender', 'birthday', 'locale']);

$userData = $socialite->user();

Log::info($userData['birthday']); // NG code
```

only birthday can not be acquired why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to approve permissions of your application from Facebook.
In your App page select tab **Status & Review** and then **Items in Review**. Select **user_birthday** and wait for approvement.